# unable to call a function on an object in a vector of objects

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a class called AI which has a save function:

```
void save(string name) {
       string fileName = "AIs/"+name+".AI";
       ofstream mySave;
       mySave.open(fileName);
       mySave << "id\n" << id << "\n";
       mySave << "pid\n" << pid <<  "\n";
       mySave << "numInpNds\n" << numInpNds << "\n";
       mySave << "numOutNds\n" << numOutNds << "\n";
       mySave << "numLayers\n" << numLayers << "\n";
       mySave << "layerSize\n";
       for (int i = 0; i < numLayers; i++) {
           mySave << layerSize[i] << "\n";
       }
       mySave << "inpLayer\n";
       mySave << nurNet["inpLayer"]<<"\n";
       for (int i = 0; i < numLayers; i++) {
           mySave << "layer"+to_string(i+1)+"Weights\n";
           mySave << nurNet["layer" + to_string(i + 1) + "Weights"] << "\n";
           mySave << "layer" + to_string(i + 1) + "Biases\n";
           mySave << nurNet["layer" + to_string(i + 1) + "Biases"] << "\n";
           mySave << "layer" + to_string(i + 1) << "\n";
           mySave << nurNet["layer" + to_string(i + 1)] << "\n";
       }
       mySave << "outLayerWeights\n";
       mySave << nurNet["outLayerWeights"] << "\n";
       mySave << "outLayerBiases\n";
       mySave << nurNet["outLayerBiases"] << "\n";
       mySave << "outLayer\n";
       mySave << nurNet["outLayer"] << "\n";
       mySave.close();
   }
```

Their is also a vector of AIs called 'AIs'.
I'm trying to iterate through this vector and save all the AIs:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < settings["generationSize"]; i++) {;
           AIs[i].save("AIs/" + to_string(i) + ".AI");
        }
```

when i try and run my code it outputs this error:

> binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::vector' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)

Comment: Use iterator for your vector. In your for loop access your vector: AIs.begin() + i. But it is better indicate AIs.size() in your for loop, because your size in settings may be different and then you will get runtime exception.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Aside: it looks like you will be saving files named like "AIs/AIs/1.AI.AI"

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Myles244/minimal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the error by moving my vector definition beneath my class definition.